# Where to find list of data types which can be casted by '::' lexem (postgresql)?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to find more about `::` sign in postgres, but failed. Where do i find comprehensive information about it (as well as which data types can be cast by this)?

> I'm trying to cast a value to serial by doing something like
>   `number::serial` and getting error "ERROR: type "serial" does not
>   exist".

I do it for educational purpuses and just started to learn SQL (as well as the PostgreSQL).

`SELECT number
FROM orders
WHERE number::serial BETWEEN 2 AND 7;`

Comment: `serial` is not a data type: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL

Comment: In addition, you can use `\dCS` in `psql` to get all existing type casts.